# Number of days between two dates - ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, date, date-arithmetic, ansi-sql

I need a way to determine the number of days between two dates in SQL.

Answer must be in ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ANSI SQL-92 defines DATE - DATE as returning an INTERVAL type.  You are supposed to be able to extract scalars from INTERVALS using the same method as extracting them from DATEs using – appropriately enough – the EXTRACT function (4.5.3).

> <extract expression> operates on
>   a datetime or interval and returns an
>   exact numeric value representing the
>   value of one component of the datetime
>   or interval.

However, this is very poorly implemented in most databases.  You're probably stuck using something database-specific.  DATEDIFF is pretty well implemented across different platforms.

Here's the "real" way of doing it.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE '2009-01-01' - DATE '2009-05-05') FROM DUAL;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I can't remember using a RDBMS that didn't support DATE1-DATE2 and [SQL 92](http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&page=ibp_60_sql_date_fs) seems to agree.

Comment: SQL Server does not support that

Comment: It sure seems so:
`SELECT GETDATE() - (GETDATE() - 5)` => 

`1900-01-06 00:00:00.000`

Comment: `getdate() - getdate()` should return `0` not `1900-01-01` according to the SQL standard

Answer (score 1):

I believe the SQL-92 standard supports subtracting two dates with the '-' operator.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 92 supports the following syntax:

```
t.date_1 - t.date_2
```

The EXTRACT function is also ANSI, but it isn't supported on SQL Server.  Example:

```
ABS(EXTRACT(DAY FROM t.date_1) - EXTRACT(DAY FROM t.date_2)
```

Wrapping the calculation in an absolute value function ensures the value will come out as positive, even if a smaller date is the first date.

EXTRACT is supported on:

- Oracle 9i+
- MySQL
- Postgres

Comment: If you EXTRACT from DATE before the subtraction, then the calculation only works if the two dates are in the same month.

Comment: In addition to EXTRACT, MS SQL server also does not support subtract operator between two dates.
    "Operand data type date is invalid for subtract operator."