# Subtracting two times to get duration

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, casting, numeric

I am trying to subtract departure time from arrival time to get the duration of trips.

The arrival/departure is in the format of HH:MM.

I'm using postgresql, the time columns just say 'string' for how they are defined. A friend helped me cast them as integers, but I'm still stick at this point:

```
SELECT x, cast (table1.arrival as integer) - cast (table.1departure as integer), sum(y), count(*)
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON .....
GROUP BY .....
ORDER BY....
```

A friend told me this but I'm not totally sure what he means: **"No you need to create a new variable for just minutes. 1:30 = 90 minutes. Cast that as integer then compute."** How do I do this?

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1800378/1678362) can be slightly modified to apply to your question.

Comment: How are these columns defined? As `varchar`s?

Comment: Is your RDBMS Mysql ?

Comment: You should always include a tag for the specific database (DBMS) you're using, as functionality and syntax varies between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column is indeed a `varchar` (or `text`) then you need to first cast the column to a proper time.

```
SELECT x, table1.arrival::time - table.1departure::time, sum(y), count(*)
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON .....
GROUP BY .....
ORDER BY.
```

The above will fail if the time stored in the columns is not a properly formatted time in 24 hour format (e.g. 22:40)

The result of `time - time` is an [interval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). If you want to get the result in minutes, you need to extract them from the interval:

```
extract(epoch from table1.arrival::time - table.1departure::time) / 60
```

`extract(epoch ..)` returns the seconds in the interval that's why you need to divide it by 60 to get minutes.

This will however not work properly if the arrival and departure time are not on the same day (e.g. departure is at 23:25 and arrival is the next day at 07:23)

---

Unrelated but: you should **never** store dates, times or timestamps in `varchar` or `text` columns. **Always** use the proper data type.

Comment: Dude....thank you so much. Worked perfectly. Yea, these tables weren't created by me so I can't explain why they weren't properly stored.

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS is Mysql you can use the MySQL DATEDIFF() Function

For example :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(arrivale,departure) AS DiffDate
```

I assume here that the arrivale and the departure are in the same day.
And that arrivale and departue are TimeDate formated like HH:MM.