# ansi sql how to select number of days since oldest timestamp in table

Tags: sql, date, ansi-sql

I have a table I want to truncate if the data accumulates more than X days

So I guess I would select the oldest timestamp first presumably by using a MIN function on the timestamp column.

and then calculate the number of days passed between that value and current_timestamp.

Is there a unified sql statement to do this (the days passed result, not the truncate)

Comment: "ANSI" SQL is not particularly useful.  Please tag the question with the database you are really using.

Comment: Why do you think you need oldest timestamp?  I think knowing if a record is older than X days is more useful.  (this is that 'truncating' means delete records older than X days)

Comment: maybe [Number of days between two dates - ANSI SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800290/number-of-days-between-two-dates-ansi-sql) helps?

Comment: looking for a unified answer. Yes I can do it in two sql calls but just wondering if anyone has a unified statement solution

Comment: Are you really just looking to do a `delete from YOUR_TABLE where RECORD_DATE < (sysdate - 365);`? (that's Oracle-flavored, but concept is the same.)  If that's not adequate, then I think you'll need to add more detail to your post.

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI SQL this would be:

```
select current_timestamp - min(the_timestamp_column)
from the_table;
```

This returns an `interval` value.

To delete rows that are older than x days, you can use a DELETE statement with the corresponding WHERE clause:

```
delete from the_table
where the_timestamp_column < current_timestamp - interval '42' day;
```

Comment: select day(current_timestamp - min(col))
from table;

Comment: @GiannaGiavelli, `DAY()` function is not ANSI SQL.